# Polymer 2 website is not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, polymer, internet-explorer-11, polymer-2.x

I am stuck with one thing. Polymer 2 website is working smoothly in Chrome and firefox, but in IE is showing error in developer tool console. It's showing Syntax error in polymer class declaration.

```js
class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'my-app'; }
}
```

Also showing "Expected :" in na-behavior.html.

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    Polymer.NoteAppBehaviorImpl = {
      properties: {
        editableNoteId: {
          type: String,
          notify: true
        }
      },

      get notesPath() {
        return '';
      },

      get isEditable() {
        return true;
      },

      toEditableId: function(noteId) {
        return noteId;
      },

      edit: function(event) {
        if (this.isEditable) {
          var noteElement = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget;
          this.editableNoteId = this.toEditableId(noteElement.id);

          this.$.document.transactionsComplete.then(function() {
            this.$.editor.open(noteElement);
          }.bind(this));
        }
      },

      create: function() {
        if (this.isEditable) {
          this.editableNoteId = null;
          this.$.editor.open();
        }
      },

      commitChange: function(event) {
        var changeCommits;

        switch (event.detail) {
          case 'save':
            changeCommits = this.save();
            break;
          case 'delete':
            changeCommits = this.delete();
            break;
          default:
            changeCommits = Promise.resolve();
            break;
        }

        if (this.$.query && this.$.query.refresh) {
          changeCommits.then(function() {
            this.$.query.refresh();
          }.bind(this));
        }
      },

      save: function() {
        if (this.$.document.isNew &&
            (this.editableNote.title ||
             this.editableNote.body)) {
          return this.$.document.save(this.notesPath).then(function() {
            this.$.document.reset();
          }.bind(this));
        }

        return Promise.resolve();
      },

      delete: function() {
        if (!this.$.document.isNew) {
          this.$.document.destroy();
        }

        return Promise.resolve();
      },

      signOut: function() {
        if (this.$.auth) {
          this.$.auth.signOut();
        }
      }
    };

    /** @polymerBehavior */
    Polymer.NoteAppBehavior = [
      Polymer.AppNetworkStatusBehavior,
      Polymer.NoteAppBehaviorImpl
    ];
  })();
```

What's the wrong with it. Anyone could you please help me? If you need more info please know me.

Comment: ES6 classes are not supported in IE. Are you creating an ES5 transpiled build?

Comment: @BenThomas   What should i do for ES5 transpiled build ?

Comment: If you are using the `polymer-cli`, there is an option in the build process to create a bundled ES5 build. More information on this can be found [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/toolbox/build-for-production). Otherwise, you will have to include babel as part of your build process in order to transpile your Polymer elements. More info on that from the Polymer website [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/es6)

Comment: @BenThomas Now i am creating ES5 build. It's working at localhost, but not working on server.

Comment: so what is the error?
you probably need more polyfills... IE11 does not have promises, nor URL support... but that really depends on what u are using in your app